# Struggling with understanding two approximations in Statistical Physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, approximations, fermi-energy

I am a student finishing my bachelors in Applied Physics, and whilst studying for Statistical Physics I came across 2 approximations I can't understand. These are the Quantum corrections for an Ideal Gas, and an approximation for a Degenerate Electron Gas.

1. The Ideal Gas with Quantum Corrections:

Starting out with a fermion gas we can deduce the following equation:
$$\frac{Pv}{k_BT} = \frac{gv}{\lambda^3}\varphi_{5/2}(f)$$
And
$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{g}{\lambda^3}\varphi_{3/2}(f)$$
Where $v= \frac{V}{N}$, $f = e^{\beta\mu}$, $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi\hbar}{mk_BT}}$, $\varphi_{\alpha}(f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}f^n}{n^{\alpha}}$ and $g$ is the degeneracy.

From my notes, we assume $\frac{v}{\lambda^3}«1$ which implies that $\varphi_{3/2}(f) « 1$. Now in my notes I simply have "we can approximate":
$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{g}{\lambda^3}\varphi_{3/2}(f) = \frac{g}{\lambda^3}(f-\frac{f^2}{2^{3/2}}+...)$$
to
$$f = \frac{\lambda^3}{gv} +\frac{\lambda^6}{(2v)^22^{3/2}}+...$$
I can't understand this rewriting of the fugacity as a sum of the products of the other side of the equation. Is this a specific type of approximation? Is it tied to the condition that $\frac{v}{\lambda^3}«1$?

2. The Degenerate Electron Gas

The state equations are approximately:

$$\frac{\lambda^3}{v}\approx\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\nu^{3/2}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8\nu^2}\right)$$
Where
$\nu = \ln{(f)} = \frac{\mu}{k_BT}$.

After this, we define the Fermi energy $(\epsilon_F)$ and establish that $\mu =\epsilon_F$, when T = 0. Then, the equation is replaced with the Fermi nu and I can't see the reason why.
$$\frac{\lambda^3}{v}\approx\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\nu^{3/2}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8\nu_F^2}\right)$$
Where $\nu_F = \frac{\epsilon_F}{k_BT}$

How can we perform this change from one equation to the other? Is this a problem with my notes? Are there steps that I am missing?

Thank you very much for your time and patience. I hope this was written in an understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be thinking more about the value of $f$

If $0<f\ll1$ then the infinite sum making up $\varphi_{3/2}(f)$ is manifestly also much less than 1, but more importantly, the infinite sum can be truncated after the first two terms, giving the approximation you want in the first part.

All you have to convince yourself, is that $\dfrac v{\lambda^3}\ll1$ implies $0<f\ll1$. This, I do not remember, and I am not about to open my textbooks to find this out.

---

The degeneracy should mean that we are now considering the opposite limit. Indeed, earlier, I was expecting $\mu<0$ and $T\gg0$ so that $0<f\ll1$. Now, we should be having $\mu>0$ and $T\to0^+$ so it should be that $f\gg1$

But your confusion here is just bizarre. Firstly, you know that $\epsilon_F=\lim_{T\to0}\mu$ and you just needed to know that $\mu$ is a pretty slowly changing function of $T$ even beyond room temperature. So, then, it would make sense to just replace appearances of $\mu$ with $\epsilon_F$ if we just want an approximation. It is typically a great approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes my confusion on the Fermi energy is weird, but I finally managed to understand. I was able to calculate the approximation you mentioned which helped clarify a lot.
As for the other question, my problem is the switch of $\frac{\lambda}{v} = A\sum{f_ib_i}$ to $f = \sum{\lambda}$.